# $\lim$ $(x,y)$ approaches $(1,0)$ for $(x^2-y^2-1)/(x^2 +y^2 -1)$?

Tags: limits

If I substitute $x=1$ and $y=0$ directly,I get $0/0$ so I subtitute $y=x-1$ and found the limit is $1$?But apparently it's undefined so what else do I substitute with to get another limit that is not $1$?

Comment: But there's a y variable so I wouldn't know whether to differentiate with respect to x or y?

Comment: Sorry you are right I will delete my comment

Comment: However this might be of use / interest https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0363.pdf

Comment: Just substitue $x = 1-y$ and you get the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

From your work, substituting $y=x-1$, we have
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{x^2-y^2-1}{x^2+y^2-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{2x-2}{2x^2-2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{x}=1$$

On the other hand, substituting $x=1$, we have
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)} \frac{x^2-y^2-1}{x^2+y^2-1}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{-y^2}{y^2}=-1$$

It may seem like my substitution of "$x=1$" is invalid (since we are told that we cannot substitute like this in 2-D limits).  But since we are proving in contradiction, with the fact that "if the limit exists, then any (relevant) substitution will give the same result", its contrapositive is that "if two (relevant) substitutions give different result, the limit does not exist".  So I think I have finished the proof.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zIQ64 I have made this by Geogebra, with the orange line being the line (x,y)=(1,0).  I guess this means it's undefined (but you can see that when y=0, it is defined, just for any neighborhood, it fails.

Comment: But shouldn't we limit x to 1?

Comment: Ahhhh right thanks @SookLim I see, wait me for a moment

Comment: There are different limits depending on the path.  If you set $y = 1-x$ you get a different answer than $x = 1-y$.

Comment: @fleablood nice one I substituted $y=1-x$ and probably because of my calculation error I cannot get different result.  Feels bad so I finally find another substitution.  But my solution is essentially the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

If the limit exists it should b consistant

$\lim_{y\to 0}(\lim_{x\to 1} \frac {x^2 -y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 -1} ) =$

$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac {-y^2}{y^2} = \lim_{y\to 0} -1 = -1$.

But $\lim_{x\to 1}(\lim_{y\to 0} \frac {x^2 -y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 -1} ) =$

But $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac {x^2 -1}{x^2 -1} = \lim_{x\to 1} 1 = 1$.

If we to $x = t; y = 1-t$ then

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac {x^2 -y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 -1} = \lim_{t\to 1} \frac {t^2 - (1 - 2t + t^2) - 1}{t^2 + (1 - 2t + t^2)-1}=$

$\lim_{t\to 1}\frac { 2t -2}{2t^2-2t}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac 1{t} = 1$.

And if $y = t$ and $x= 1-t$ then

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac {x^2 -y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 -1} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac {(1-t)^2  -t^2 -1}{(1-t)^2 +2t +1}=$

$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac { -2t}{2+t^2}=0$.

No consistant limit exists.